# Curly Brace expected error? How do I fix it?

Tags: curly-braces

I have looked through other questions after Visual Studio gave me error CS1513, saying it's expecting a curly bracket, where I already have a curly bracket.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGlQ3.jpg

Comment: Please post a MCVE next time in form of code, not a screenshot. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You mixed **while** with **else if**.